# Crash when using PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, ios10, photosframework

I am using `PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset` to load some videos from the camera roll:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("SEGUE SUCCESSFUL")
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    var asset2:AVAsset? = nil

    PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: (vidLocation?[videoSender]!)!, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
        asset2 = asset! as AVAsset
        })


    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset2!)
    avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
}
```

However when I run the program it pauses at the `PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset` line and shows:

> THREAD 1 : EXC_BREAKPOINT

(highlighted in green)

I'm not sure what is happening and can't find anything I understand in the documentation.  How do I fix this?

Comment: You have two force-unwrap operations in one of the parameters to that call (`(vidLocation?[videoSender]!)!`). Probably at least one of them is nil. Also, while it's unrelated to your crash you have an incorrect assumption — the completion handler for `requestAVAsset` is asynchronous, so it'll execute *after* the code that sets your `playerItem`, so `asset2` will always be nil at the time you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you're going to want to do here in order to get this working.

1. You need to cache the `PHCachingImageManager` as a property on an object that will stay alive. If you just create it without storing it somewhere, ARC rules will cause it to be thrown away. In the code below, I use a lazy var, but that's not the only way to do it.
2. You should eliminate all forced unwrapped optionals `!` in your code. Using the `guard let ...` or `if let ...` patterns may feel like more typing but it will save you a lot of time and frustration in the end. Think of the `!` as a danger sign that says "**CRASH HERE!**".
3. You need to set up the `AVPlayerItem` from the `resultHandler` completion block. `requestAVAsset` is asynchronous so that it doesn't block your main thread while it does the potentially expensive work of retrieving your asset. Basically, as soon as you call `requestAVAsset` a separate thread goes and does work for you, while the main thread continues working on the rest of the code in the `viewDidLoad` method. When it has successfully retrieved the `AVAsset` it calls back to the block of code you provided originally (on the main thread) so you can continue processing.

Here's your code rewritten to incorporate the changes I'm suggesting:

```
lazy var imageManager = {
    return PHCachingImageManager()
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("SEGUE SUCCESSFUL")
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    var asset2:AVAsset? = nil
guard let phAsset = vidLocation?[videoSender] else { return } //No video

imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: phAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
    if let avAsset = asset {
        self.play(asset: avAsset)
    }
})

func play(asset: AVAsset) {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Perfect - this did the job.   The only edit to the code is in this line:   `guard let phAsset = vidLocation?[videoSender] else { return //No video }`    I had to change it to this:      `guard let phAsset = vidLocation?[videoSender] else { return } //No video `     Else the closing bracket of the else is commented out.